# How to update popup after dragging the marker?

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, leaflet

I have a leaflet map where i am using Control Geocoder to get some locations on search,then i add the coordinates on 2 input fields,also i added a popup for the search result,the problem is that when the marker is moved the popup doesn't update with the new place,how can this be done?

```
Mmap = L.map('Modalmap').setView([8.7144, 125.7481],8);
L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright"></a>',
    subdomains: ['a','b','c']
}).addTo(Mmap);
var geocoder = L.Control.geocoder({
    defaultMarkGeocode: false,
    draggable:true
})
.on('markgeocode', function(e) {
    var box = e.geocode.center;
    var name=e.geocode.name;
    document.getElementById("Latitude").value = box.lat;
    document.getElementById("Longitude").value = box.lng;
    MarkLayer=L.marker([box.lat,box.lng],{draggable:true}).addTo(Mmap). 
    on('dragend', onDragEnd). 
    bindPopup(e.geocode.name). 
    openPopup(); 
    displayLatLng(box); 

    group = new L.featureGroup([MarkLayer]);

    Mmap.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
}).addTo(Mmap); 

function onDragEnd(event) 
{
    var latlng = event.target.getLatLng();

    displayLatLng(latlng);
}

function displayLatLng(latlng) {
    document.getElementById("Latitude").value = latlng.lat;
    document.getElementById("Longitude").value = latlng.lng;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code. It is quite logical, if you drag the marker, it won't necessary fall on a new place with a name. Or do you want to put `lat, long` data into your popup?

Comment: @juminet...when geocoding done at the first time,it shows street name or building number,when i drag it,it is supposed to give me the new street name for example but it  gives me the same result of the first point.

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418216/how-to-update-popup-after-dragging-the-marker

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.reverse` function to do a reverse geocoding, that is, retrieving a name for a latitude-longitude coordinate.

To use that you have to create a geocoder instance. I chose the default here, which is Nominatim. It might help to rename your current `geocoder` control to `geocoderControl` or something else.

```
var geocoderNominatim = new L.Control.Geocoder.Nominatim();
var geocoderControl = L.Control.geocoder({
    geocoder: geocoderNominatim
}) // etc.
```

And then perform this reverse lookup in your `onDragEnd` and apply the new popup contents:

```
function onDragEnd(event) {
    var latlng = event.target.getLatLng();

    geocoderNominatim.reverse(latlng, Mmap.options.crs.scale(Mmap.getZoom()), function(reverseGeocoded){
      event.target.setPopupContent(reverseGeocoded[0].name).openPopup();
    }, this)

    displayLatLng(latlng);
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/kvAy4wABFIBOnb3JBr6i?p=preview)